# GNU make: define, eval and multiple-files targets

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm trying the following Makefile, right now I'm stuck on this error and I need some help (and maybe some advices).

This is what I want to achieve: I have a program that produces a lot of output files starting from a bunch of other files living in the same directory. Then I have to run this program for several of those directories. Each target will be something like this:

```
output_1 output_2 ... output_n : input_1 input_2 ... input_m
    program args
```

This is the full Makefile:

```
SRCDIR  = <...>
DESTDIR = <...>
JOBT4Z  = <...>

# function to change the position of the directory tree
changetree = $(shell echo $(2)/$(shell echo $(1) | rev | cut -d'/' -f-4 | rev))

# get all directories with input files to be processed
DIRS = $(wildcard ../../*/*/*/edep ../../*/*/*/coin)

# extract infos from path to later build output file names
volume  = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -d "/" -f3)
part    = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -d "/" -f4)
isotope = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -d "/" -f5)
deptype = $(shell echo $(1) | cut -d "/" -f6)

# array with runIDs
RUNS = $(shell seq 53 65) 67 $(shell seq 69 89)

# function to build the output file name
# ARG1: directory with raw files
# ARG2: runID
t4zfile = t4z-$(call volume,$(1))-$(call part,$(1))-$(call isotope,$(1))-$(call deptype,$(1))-run$(2).root

# function to get the list of output files that will be created for one job
# ARG1: directory with input files
out4zfiles = $(foreach id,$(RUNS),$(call changetree,$(1)/$(call t4zfile,$(1),$(id)),$(DESTDIR)))

# variable holding *all* the output files
ALLT4Z = $(foreach dir,$(DIRS),$(call out4zfiles,$(dir)))

all : $(ALLT4Z)

# the dependencies are set to be the input files, so if they change the
# corresponding output files are re-processed
define t4z-recipe-template
  $(call out4zfiles,$(1)) : $(wildcard $(call changetree,$(1),$(SRCDIR))/raw-*.root)
  $(JOBT4Z) $(call changetree,$(1),$(SRCDIR)) $(DESTDIR) > /dev/null
endef

# run!
$(foreach dir,$(DIR),$(eval $(call t4z-recipe-template,$(dir))))

clean :
    -rm -rf $(T4ZFILES)

.PHONY : clean all
```

The core lines are:

```
define t4z-recipe-template
  $(call out4zfiles,$(1)) : $(wildcard $(call changetree,$(1),$(SRCDIR))/raw-*.root)
  $(JOBT4Z) $(call changetree,$(1),$(SRCDIR)) $(DESTDIR) > /dev/null
endef

# run!
$(foreach dir,$(DIR),$(eval $(call t4z-recipe-template,$(dir))))
```

All the rest is essentially playing with strings, I've already debugged it, it should work as expected.

First of all, if I try to run it I get a "missing separator" error from the `$(foreach dir,$(DIR),$(eval $(call t4z-recipe-template,$(dir))))` line, and I don't know why. Secondly, I'm sure that this won't work because `$(call out4zfiles,$(1))` won't be expanded *in the same* target.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This is a very complicated makefile. Have you read our page on [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? I you have tested these functions and are confident that they work correctly, you can simplify the example a great deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "missing separator" error comes from a missing `tab` in the `define` section, though idkw the example reported [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html) works without it... Also putting a semicolon `;` and a line break `\` after the prerequisites list works, obviously.

Looking a little bit more into the docs I realised that a multiple-items target is actually equivalent to a rule for each item, so there's no actual need to have it.